# check if screen not visible react native

Tags: javascript, android, ecmascript-6, react-native

Hello guys I was wondering is there any hook or something that would help me to know if my current screen is going out of visibility i.e I have clicked some other tab which will take me to another screen.

Here is an example

I have screen A and screen B. Screen A is currently visible. Now if I click on a tab which takes me to screen B is there any way for screen A to know that it is going out focus i.e it is not visible to the user anymore

Comment: onPause lifecycle hook? `AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);` where the handler is your defined. you have 3 states: foreground, background and inactive. [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) the doc

Comment: @FeMachine I have used it but they are for app going into background or foreground. My use case is for the screen if it is in foreground of background

Comment: read discussion https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/962 . No solution out of the box, but you can find work code there